# What type of documentation does WordPress code follow?

Tags: php, wordpress, documentation, phpdoc

I am trying to begin using some sort of standard for documenting my PHP code.  Most of my code is in the form of WordPress plugins, some are getting quite complex, and I need to document it.

So my question is simple, what system does WordPress use to document their code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it uses [phpDoc](http://www.phpdoc.org/).

There is also a [guide for WordPress inline documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Inline_Documentation).

Comment: I think you are right, it uses all the same tags. Good link, thanks.